# OpenFire Server check connection for XMPP

Tags: android, openfire

I am using open fire in my application but i could not check my user is connected or not with server please suggest me how to check.

Comment: what you tried so far ?  can you please post code ? and openfire is for server side from client which you have used ? asmack , smack or what ?

Comment: check given answer method:-

Answer (score -1):

check this given method

```
 public XMPPConnection connect(final String username, final String password,
                              final String host, final String service, final String port) {
    // Create a connection
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
    connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);


    try {
        connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
        connection.connect();
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "
                + connection.getHost());
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
    }

    //Login to the server
    try {
        connection.login(username, password, "Smack" + new Date().getTime());
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);// Set the presence to available
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + username);
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        return null;
    }
    //initialize();


    initialize();//Add packet listener on connection for listen any message received

    return connection;
}
```

this connection object will help you to find your user is connected or not